# Этимология слова "щи"

Tags: этимология

Тут однажды прозвучал фееричный вопрос: "как будет "щи" в единственном числе?"))) А в самом деле, откуда взялось это слово, означающее капустный суп?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ну вообще-то это два совершенно не связанных вопроса.
Не помню, чтобы этот вопрос именно в таком виде звучал здесь, но единственное число восстанавливается по родительному падежу множественного числа (щей) и дает "щъ" или "щь", как хрящ(ъ) - хрящей, борщ(ъ) - борщей или вещь - вещей.
Первое вероятнее, поскольку грамматический род восстанавливается из дореволюционной орфографии, писалось "кислые щи", в женском было бы кисл**ыя**.
Такого же мнения придерживается и Зализняк, давая "щам" мужской род.

Разумеется, реально такого слова никогда в единственном числе не существовало.
По поводу этимологии подробная статья есть у Фасмера, который возводит щи к сътъ - еда, пропитание, отсюда "сытый". С падением редуцированных СъТ превратилось в ШТ, а это именно то сочетание, которое и породило современный звук Щ во всех случаях его современного использования.

мн., диал. шти "похлебка из сушеной рыбы и крупы", олонецк. (Кулик.), кирилловск., шенкурск., "варево, похлебка, суп, заправленный капустой, щавелем и другой зеленью", севск. (Преобр.), шти, также в знач. "дикий лук", колымск. (Богораз). Отсюда производные: ща́ги мн. "щи", прилаг. щано́й; др.-русск. шти мн., род. п. штей (Домостр. Заб. 55 и сл.; К. 41 и др., также у Радищева), кислаштяной (Домостр. К. 28), собств. Иван Шти, грам. 1510 г.; см. Соболевский, Лекции 119. Возм., щи восходит к *сътъ, мн. съти (ср. сот), др.-русск. съто "пропитание"; см. Соболевский, там же; ЖМНП, 1886, сент., стр. 145 и сл.; Чернышев, Сб. Соболевскому 28; Горяев, Доп. I, 47 и сл.; Черных, Лексикол. 190. Менее вероятно родство со щаве́ль и др.-инд. суávаtē "приводит в движение, сотрясает" (см. Потебня, РФВ, 1881, 4, 67; Мi. ЕW 343; Горяев, ЭС 429, отчасти также Младенов 697), а также сближение с сок (см.) с реконструкцией не засвидетельствованного нигде *съкъ (Ильинский, РФВ 73, 305 и сл.). Из последнего ожидалось бы *сци. Следует отвергнуть сближение со *sьсаti (Брандт, РФВ 24, 192). По мнению Б. де Куртенэ (у Даля 4, 1506 и сл.), щи заимств. из датск. skу "похлебка, навар", но последнее само заимств. из франц. jus "сок" (Фальк–Торп 1044).

Comment: У ДАля есть слово ЩА как диалектное со значением всякий овощ и зелень, но не капуста. А множественное от него - ЩИ.

Comment: Да, я вроде бы сталкивался. Но, полагаю, это вторично. Ибо мужской род вполне очевиден.  

Хотя... Вы знаете, сейчас подумал, прилагательное "щаной" заставляет считаться и с вариантом "ща" для единственного числа. От "щъ" было бы "щной"/"щ(Е)ный" или "щовый": Вещь - вещный, хрящ - хрящевой...
  
А, нет, вру. Рожь - ржаной. Все правильно. Щаной от "щъ" вполне возможно. Так что "ща" - это позднейшее.

Comment: Щавьный - кислый, соотносится со щавелем. Кислые щи - род кваса. Похлебка капустная ли, крапивная, или со щавелем - однозначно с кислинкой. Все это овощи/овошти. Славяне европейские называют щи - капустник или "зелень". Овощ(а)ной суп.

Comment: >Щавьный - кислый, соотносится со щавелем.   
  
Ну да. А что?  
  
>Кислые щи - род кваса.   
  
Знаем. Могу даже рецептиком снабдить. Только это совсем не квас, а напиток, похожий на сидр. Делается из любой фрукты-ягоды, даже ананасов. 
 
На грамматике не сказывается. Возьмите грорячие щи. Они все равно "горячiе" были, не "горячiя".

Comment: "А щи горячие, да с кипяточечком, А слезы катятся, да ручеечечком!" :)
Горячущие щи, прямо страсть.

Comment: Вообще-то, вопрос был не об единственном числе, а о этимологии слова. behemothus, читайте вопросы внимательнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: Fuchoin Kazuki, я видел.

>>Тут однажды прозвучал фееричный вопрос: "как будет "щи" в единственной числе?" А в самом деле, откуда взялось это слово, означающее капустный суп?  
  
Автор явно связывает два вопроса. Почему бы не ответить на оба?